# open addressing hash table with no collision

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, addressing

I'm trying to find an efficient C++ implementation of an hash table using open addressing. I've tried using https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash with no success.

In addition it would be a plus if :
- the container would know that my hash method is guaranteed without collision.
- the container had a constant-time method to access first free key.

Am I really looking for a hash table ? If yes, do you know such implementation ? If not, what would best suit my needs ?

Thx a lot,
vob

Comment: What is "no success" and what are you asking? It's pretty hard to guess what you're looking for

Comment: no success = the library is not working (missing files apparently).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the phrase "perfect hashing."  An code generator to create such a function is gperf: https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/  Once you have that, you should implement your own hash table--perhaps you can start here: https://gist.github.com/jorendorff/b6afda0f5ae670b8ebb3

Comment: I said my hash method is guaranteed without collision, I didn't say I need a new hash method u_u But if the table knows I guess it can optimize